# Dagger2 not finding provided instance

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I'm facing some issues trying to use Dagger with multiple Components, I have the following (each class is in its own file):

Scopes:

```
@Scope
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class PrototypeScope
```

Modules:

```
@Module(includes = [RepositoriesModule::class])
class GetRandomBookUseCaseModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGetRandomBookUseCase(booksRepository: BooksRepository) =
        GetRandomBookUseCase(booksRepository)
}


@Module
class RepositoriesModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesBooksRepository(): BooksRepository = BooksRepositoryImpl()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesPreferencesRepository(): PreferencesRepository = PreferencesRepositoryImpl()
}


@Module
class BookReaderModule(val ctx: Context) {

    @Provides
    @PrototypeScope
    fun provideBookReader(getRandomBookUseCase: GetRandomBookUseCase) =
        BookReader(ctx, getRandomBookUseCase)
}
```

Components:

```
@Component(
    modules = [GetRandomBookUseCaseModule::class]
)
interface UseCasesComponent {

}

@Component(
    dependencies = [UseCasesComponent::class],
    modules = [BookReaderModule::class]
)
@PrototypeScope
interface BookReaderFragmentComponent {

    fun inject(bookReaderFragment: BookReaderFragment)
}
```

Then, in BookReaderFragment I have the following:

```
class BookReaderFragment : Fragment() {
    @Inject lateinit var bookReader: BookReader
    val component: BookReaderFragmentComponent by lazy {
        DaggerBookReaderFragmentComponent
            .builder()
            .useCasesComponent(DaggerUseCasesComponent.create())
            .bookReaderModule(BookReaderModule(context!!))
            .build()
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        component.inject(this)
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

However, Dagger is failing ought to:

```
error: GetRandomBookUseCase cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
```

What is going on? Why Dagger is not finding the provided method?

Thanks a lot

UPDATE: Adding RepositoriesModule as included in GetRandomBookUseCaseModule. After this change, I have realised that, although the error message, the issue is related with the way the BookReader is injected.
If I remove the @Injected from the BookReaderFragment this way:

```
class BookReaderFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var bookReader: BookReader
    val component: BookReaderFragmentComponent by lazy {
        DaggerBookReaderFragmentComponent
            .builder()
            .useCasesComponent(DaggerUseCasesComponent.create())
            .bookReaderModule(BookReaderModule(context!!))
            .build()
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        component.inject(this)
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Then there's no error, however it will not work on runtime, but when the @Inject is set, then the error is thrown.

Comment: in GetRandomBookUseCase constructor,add @Inject above it

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've added the Inject as you said, but then the error has changed to: BooksRepository cannot be provided without an Provides-annotated method. :( I don't understand, because I'm creating the GetRandomBookUseCase in its own module with component dependencies.

Comment: you must add @Inject in every constructor of depedencies you want to create.Inject is just like you say to Dagger that " hey,this is what i need to create and how you create me".like it say in document **@Inject: request dependencies. Can be used on a constructor, a field, or a method*

Comment: > Parent component must explicitly declare objects which can be used in child components.

The answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59560543/3040498) is the correct way, you can read more [here](https://proandroiddev.com/dagger-2-part-ii-custom-scopes-component-dependencies-subcomponents-697c1fa1cfc#9760)

Comment: I've tried adding `@Inject` into BooksRepository constructor, like` class BooksRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor() : BooksRepository {...}` but the error is still saying: BooksRepository cannot be provided without an Provides-annotated method.

Comment: you say **@Singleton
   fun providesBooksRepository(): BooksRepository = BooksRepositoryImpl()* is singleton,did your BookRepositoryImpl is @Singleton too?

Comment: No, it is not. Should it be Singleton? Why should I add the Inject and Singleton in classes? Shouldn't it be enough setting them in modules and components?

Comment: look like i was wrong,your setting is enough :D

Comment: how @Inject work is what i posted above

Comment: i think it should work as well with the answer below.try to clean project or restart AS ( sometime dagger generate code not work so well lol)

Comment: I have updated the answer, because I've realised that the error is only thrown when the `@Inject` of bookReader is set; if not set, then the error is not thrown. However, it will fail at runtime as the bookReader will have not been initialized.

Comment: could you provide your GetRandomBookUseCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `RepositoriesModule` into `GetRandomBookUseCaseModule`

```
@Module(includes = {RepositoriesModule.class})
class {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGetRandomBookUseCase(booksRepository: BooksRepository) =
        GetRandomBookUseCase(booksRepository)
}
```

And Component should be

```
@Component(
    modules = [GetRandomBookUseCaseModule::class]
)
interface UseCasesComponent {
    GetRandomBookUseCase getRandomBookUseCase();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've tried it, but the error doesn't change :(

Comment: Can you update your code with the changes so that I can check?

Comment: Also you have to provide `UseCasesComponent` to `DaggerBookReaderFragmentComponent` builder to resolve dependency

Comment: I have updated the code in my question, I haven't added the `UseCasesComponent` to `DaggerBookReaderFragmentComponent ` yet, because the build is currently failing with error: GetRandomBookUseCase cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.

Comment: First try to complete `UseCasesComponent` and then start to merge with `BookReaderFragmentComponent`. Bty `GetRandomSongUseCaseModule` is missing too

Comment: Sorry, GetRandomSongUseCaseModule doesn't exist, it is GetRandomBookUseCaseModule instead (I've already updated it). The real project is more complex, and I'm trying to add just the pieces of code that are involved in the error

Comment: I've updated the question, I have realised that the issue is related with the way I'm injecting the bookReader to my fragment. If `@Inject` is set, then the error is thrown; if it is not set, then the error is never thrown, however it will fail at runtime

Comment: You're right; I have accepted your answer as your answer is really the solution of my issue, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the issue: I was not returning the getRandomBookUseCase in UseCasesComponent, finally I have changed the UseCasesComponent to:

```
@Component(
    modules = [GetRandomBookUseCaseModule::class]
)
@Singleton
interface UseCasesComponent {

    val getRandomBookUseCase: GetRandomBookUseCase
}
```

And BookReaderComponent to:

```
@Component(
    dependencies = [UseCasesComponent::class],
    modules = [BookReaderModule::class]
)
@PrototypeScope
interface BookReaderFragmentComponent {

    val bookReader: BookReader
}
```

Then in the fragment I use it as:

```
class BookReaderFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var bookReader: BookReader
    val component: BookReaderFragmentComponent by lazy {
        DaggerBookReaderFragmentComponent
            .builder()
            .useCasesComponent(DaggerUseCasesComponent.create())
            .bookReaderModule(BookReaderModule(context!!))
            .build()
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        bookReader = component.bookReader
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Thank you very much for all your help, you really help me a lot to solve my issue.